# When should Angular become a tag synonym for Angular 2?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

While Angular 2 is still in beta, it stands to reason that eventually Angular 2 could surpass the popularity of Angular 1. Additionally, the Angular team refers to Angular 2 as simply Angular, while 1 is typically called Angular.js.

It makes sense at some point to migrate the tag synonym from Angular -> Angular.js to Angular -> Angular 2. At what point should this occur? Upon an official Angular 2 release? Upon a certain threshold of adoption / popularity on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Gimby I'm asking about the tag synonym `Angular` and which one it should map to.

Comment: Derp, I responded backwards. Here's the reverse: IMO it should actually be both. "Angular" refers to the body of work that is Angular, which at the time of writing comprises of Angular.JS and Angular 2. Both iterations are not going to be irrelevant any time soon after all.

Comment: Since Angular 2 is not backwards-compatible with Angular 1, I'm guessing it's when no one is using Angular 1 any more. So, two to five years from now? I'm currently working on an Angular 1 site that won't be upgraded to Angular 2 earlier than that, and I expect questions for Angular 1 to continue at least that long. Angular 2 has to be out of beta for at least a year before some companies will consider it...

Comment: @Gimby That's not the point I'm trying to make though. "Angular" is a more appropriate name for Angular 2 than for Angular 1, per the team's own terminology. Keep all the tags involved, I just think at some point (soon) Angular should be a synonym for 2 and not for 1.

Comment: Correct, The Angular team is now referring to Angular 1.x as "Angular.js" and Angular 2.x and above is now being referred to as just "Angular."  We need to make this change to the tags as well as the Documentation Titles.  Here is the documentation confirming that:  http://www.infoworld.com/article/3150716/application-development/forget-angular-3-google-skips-straight-to-angular-4.html

Comment: @aholtry Even more relevant now that we're on Angular 4+.